# convert date from number format to date format dd/mm/YYY

Tags: javascript

I have a date value stored as number '44567' that i would like to convert to date format using javascript

```
var datexx = new Date(44567).toDate("dd/mm/YYYY");
                        console.log('date: ', datexx);
```

on excel file this value is equal to 06/01/2022

thank you

Comment: How can `44567` be converted to a date...?

Comment: it has been converted like so after an upload of data from excel file. On excel it happens when changing date format to number

Comment: 44567 might be timestamp.

Comment: After researching it appears Excel interprets 5 digit timestamps as days since 01-01-1900. So to convert your value to a date you just need to add that many days on, which can be done like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/563442/519413